# Quantified Logic with miltuple variables

Tags: logic

Problem: 
∀y¬∃x¬(¬Fxy ∨ Fyx) ⊢ ∀y∀z(Fyz→Fzy)

I don't really understand how to deal with multiple variables in instances like this. So far I have:

```
1)∀y¬∃x¬(¬Fxy ∨ Fyx)    A
2)show ∀y∀z(Fyz→Fzy)
3)|show Fbc→Fzy
4)||Fbc                  ACP
5)||∀y∀x¬¬(¬Fxy ∨ Fyx) QN,1
6)||¬¬(¬Fxy ∨ Fyx)       ¬¬E,5
7)||¬Fab ∨ Fba
```

But I don't know how I can relate the two given formulas if they're have different variables. I've tried looking around but can't find anything on how to deal with multiple variables for a single predicate. Any help would be appreciated. The remaining problems on my homework deal with a similar structure to this one so any help on this would aid me a lot.

Comment: Are you missing a negation in the Problem? Because on line (1) of your proof you have a $\lnot$ before $Fxy$ but in the Problem $Fxy$ appears without a $\lnot$.

Answer (score 1):

A standard natural deduction proof goes like this:

$1.\quad \quad\forall y\neg\exists x\neg(\neg Fxy \lor Fyx) \quad\quad\quad\text{assumption}$

$2.\quad \quad \neg\exists x\neg(\neg Fay \lor Fya) \quad\quad\quad\quad\text{univ. instantion}$

$3.\quad \quad \forall x \neg\neg(\neg Fay \lor Fya) \quad\quad\quad\quad\text{by negated-quantifier rule}$

$4.\quad \quad \neg\neg(\neg Fab \lor Fba) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{univ. instantion}$

$5.\quad \quad (\neg Fab \lor Fba) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{double negation rule}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\vdots\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$

$n.\quad\quad (Fab \to Fba)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{by some propositional calculus stuff}$

$n+1.\quad\forall z (Faz \to Fza)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{univ. generalization}$

$n+2.\quad\forall y\forall z (Fyz \to Fzy)\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{univ. generalization}$

And in one natural layout scheme there aren't  any indented subproofs introduced by the universal quantifier rules (though subproofs will be involved in the propositional logic bit, since the conditional will get established by a use of conditional proof). A layout scheme like the one Hunan is using is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Step (2) takes care of that move you call 'QN' (Quantifier Negation perhaps). The Barwise & Etchemendy system doesn't have QN, so I've used the 'FO Con' shortcut in its stead.

[image]

<sub>† Thanks to Peter Smith for pointing out a shortcoming in my previous proof. Hope this one is more to his liking.</sub>

Comment: Let me know if any of the steps is puzzling. The idea is to pick arbitrary objects a,b; instantiate the given universals by substituting them for x,y in the desired order; obtain the conditional, and generalize.

Comment: The move e.g. from 1 to 2, although intuitively valid, would be illegitimate in any textbook formal natural deduction system known to me, where the rules only allow you to operate on the main operators of a wff (in this case, the outermost quantifier). So out of interest, which textbook allows the moves from 1 to 2, or from 2 to 3?

Comment: @PeterSmith the method used in Hunans proof is from "Language Proof and Logic" by Barker-Plummer cs. FO Con is not a genuine Inference rule it is a shortcut (Fo Con stands for First Order Concequence) handy if you just want to test an inference without doing all the steps.

Comment: @PeterSmith As Willemien indicated, there is no such rule in the Barwise and Etchemendy system; I cited "FO Con" to take care of the idea that: since $\lnot \exists \lnot x$ is a definitional abbreviation of $\forall x$, one can be replaced with the other in any context. I don't think that's a generally applicable rule, but here its use doesn't strike me as controversial. Thank you for your comment; it has encouraged me to type up a less shortcut-y proof.